# Filtering by category

Tags: python, django, database

I want to filter by categories. I have a lot of categories and they are translated into 3 languages. They also can be added dynamically. Now I am filtering by primary key and it seems to work fine, but I need to have the category 'All' which will be selected by default. How can I avoid hardcode values for this category?

```
def autocomplete(request):
    if 'term' in request.GET:
        term = request.GET.get('term')
        qs = Article.objects.all()
        if 'category_id' in request.GET:
            category_id = request.GET.get('category_id')
            # 4 stands for all category
            if category_id != '4':
                qs = qs.filter(category__pk=category_id)

        qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=term)
        names = []
        for article in qs:
           names.append(article.name)

        return JsonResponse(names, safe=False)
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: would you clarify what you need exactly. I think you need to get the check the latest category id?

Comment: @NKSM hello, thank you for putting effort into the answer. I was asking more about how to remove hardcoded value such as 4, because I think that this is unreliable. If the category will be deleted and created again 4 will not be category 'All' again. But I guess I can't do that. But your code looks more readable, so I will use it

Comment: @SivaSankar  I need to filter by a category, but if the category is 'All', then I need to return all article objects. As I said above, I don't think that my approach of hardcoding id value for category 'All' is reliable. What if id for this category will change? I am looking for a more reliable approach

Comment: you need to get the latest id right?

Comment: @SivaSankar no, not the latest, because the admin can always add a new category

Comment: i didn't understood. what do you need exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228098/discussion-between-siva-sankar-and-serghey-hmeli).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below code:

```
def autocomplete(request):
    term = request.GET.get('term')
    category_id = request.GET.get('category_id')
    if term:
        qs = Article.objects.all()
        # Not empty and not 4 stands for all category
        if category_id and category_id != '4':
            qs = qs.filter(category__pk=category_id)
        # filter by term
        qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=term)
        # get name values and convert queryset to list
        names = list(qs.values_list("name", flat=True))
        return JsonResponse(names, safe=False)
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```